# Two different App centres appearing in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-center

I just fresh installed Ubuntu 20.04 and during my initial start Ubuntu software centre was not working.

Hence I have reinstalled using the following command:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-software
```

But for some reason, there are two software centres are installed.
So I have completed removed package and cleared cache and then reinstalled but still same issue.

I just want to get rid of duplicate one - please help me.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I Just tried your command `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-software` this command seems to install additional things.. in which one is that Software I guess..

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqerY.png

Comment: Which center do you want to keep? And what’s you menu?

Comment: All - This is now resolved based on the below answer. BTW I'm using ARC menu (Mint Layout) thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the snap version and delete the gnome software run:

```
sudo apt remove gnome-software
```

If you want to remove the snap run:

`sudo snap remove snap-store`